# vector comparison and new assignment

Tags: matlab, classification, label

I'd like to ask you  question about some matlab code I wrote, But first of all tell you my problem. I have 2 vectors, Test Labels and Predicted labels and I want to compare them for classification reasons. Further more I want to allocate some labels new. so I have something like this 111121111 = 1 or 1122222222 =2 which I want to achieve. My code is

```
y = [];
for k = 10:length(predictedLabel)-10
    y = [y; newlabel(predictedLabel, k, 5)];
end
```

and the function newlabel is

```
function [nl] = newlabel(x, n, L)
   numClasses = 3;
   x1 = x(n-L:n+L);
   c = zeros(numClasses, 1);
   for k=1:length(x1)
     c(x1(k)) = c(x1(k))+1;
   end
  [~,nl]=max(c);
end
```

My problem is now that I result following vector lengths

```
 predictedLabel = 4996*1;
 k=4986*1;
 y=4977*1;
```

and I can't see my mistake

Any help is appreciated even new ideas with probability estimations

Thanks

loop

Comment: Your problem is the length? How long you want them to be? 
It's normal that you have this dimension because for y you use negative padding of 10 and for k of 5.

Comment: Perhaps you could not only explain what you get, but also what you expected the variables to be (and why).

Comment: I'd like to have an equal length vecotor. But what I realy want is some sort of Maximum a priori measure on comparison of the two vectors. Like I discribed them above. The problem is I don't know how to program this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- when using the length function on a scalar value it gives 1 then the value inside the for loop becomes from 10:1-10 which is meaningless. (If you want to use decreasing step you should provide something like this 10:-1:1).

2- if you want to make a vector with the size of 4996x1 it would be like this : zeros(4996,1) or ones(4996,1) or sth like this.

3- tell us about your desired result and your error.... the description is not obvious to me.